# Run dotnet ef scaffold within C# appllication

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Is it possible to run a scaffold inside a WPF .NET Core application?

Something like this?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = @"dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 'Data Source = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = Chinook' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer";

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Anything's possible given enough time and money.  Why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible, but you need to run it from within either "cmd.exe" or "powershell"

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/C dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 'Data Source = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = Chinook' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer";

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        Console.Read();
```